# <tr> tag is not creating new row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is the table I have in my view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllCommonMatches.Length; i++)
{
    <tr class="category">
        <td>//somestuff</td>          
        <td>//some stuff</td>
        <td>//some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subcategory" style="display:none">
        @foreach (var person in Model.AllCommonMatches[i].AvailableAttendees)
        {

            <td>@person.Email &nbsp; &nbsp; @person.FirstName &nbsp;&nbsp;@person.LastName</td>    

        }
    </tr>
}
```

And there is a click event for table rows

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.category').on('click', function () {
            $(this).next('.subcategory').fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Whenever table row is click, it expands and shows some data

Here is the **Generated Html**

```
 <tr class="subcategory" style="">
    <td>biplov.cybercop@hotmail.com &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>yo@yo.com &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>foo@foo.com &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

as you can see there are three email address just below the dates.
I want each email to appear as separate row. So, when row with date is clicked each email occupies an entire row.

This is what I tried (puting `<tr>` tag inside the `foreach` statement)

```
foreach (var person in somecase)
{
    <tr>
    <td>@person.Email &nbsp; &nbsp; @person.FirstName &nbsp;&nbsp;@person.LastName</td>    
    </tr>
}
```

but now when the row with date is clicked with date it shows only one row.
Nothing happens now, when I click the row. New row doesn't appear to show emails

Comment: You have style style="display:none" => will not show

Comment: yea but shouldn't the javascript show it? I get One table row shown when there is a click, but multiple rows doesn't show

Comment: the best is if you put it to (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: try to create an embed table for the list of Attendees, those may vary per event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next` and select the very next DOM element. I think you actually want `nextUntil` :

```
$(this).nextUntil('.category').fadeToggle();
```

- [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

Comment: That didn't work. I added nextuntill but when I click the row nothing appears then. No console error too

Comment: @Biplov13 show me what you did, i can't see why it would not work.

Comment: @Biplov13 not `.nextUntil('.subcategory')`, but `.nextUntil('.category')`!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next/), `next()` gets the immediately following sibling.

Means only one, not 3.

Comment: So, what should I do to show all the elements then?